Is the scalar field in the Yukawa interaction real or complex?
Consider a theory containing a Dirac field $\psi$ and a scalar field $\varphi$ where the only interaction is given by a Yukawa potential
$$
V = -g\bar{\psi}\varphi\psi
$$
I know that real scalar fields cannot couple to the electromagnetic field because their Noether current density
$$\mathcal{J}^\mu = \varphi\partial^\mu\varphi - \varphi\partial^\mu\varphi$$
under the $\text{U}(1)$ symmetry of the EM field vanishes and therefore there is no coupling (cf. this question). Is the reason that the real scalar field theory is not invariant under $\text{U}(1)$ transformations at all?

$V$ has to be real. What does this imply for $\varphi$?

it implies that $\varphi$ must be real. thanks!

The current $\bar\psi \gamma^\mu \psi$ will  be equal to zero if $\psi$ is a Majorana fermion. This condition is the fermion analogue of being "real."

I am looking explicitly for the case where $\psi$ is a Dirac fermion.

Then I do not understand your question. Perhaps you say what you mean by a "similar argument"?  What are you trying to show?

I just realized that the way I wrote it makes no sense. I will think about it again and then edit the question accordingly.

Wow, reminding me of congressmen talking PASS each other.
